# Filter in read with Library graph

Tags: cosmicmind

i've create an entity with library graph in my app  with field name and surname, i've inserted a record perfetto
Now how can i fetch from entity only one name?
Thanks
Umberto

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear. I think you want to search Graph for an Entity with a property key, is that correct? If so, here is what you would be looking for.

```
let graph: Graph = Graph()
let collection: Array<Entity> = graph.searchForEntity(properties: [(key: "name", value: nil)])
```

The collection will hold all the Entities that have the property key of `name`.

Comment: Sorry for my english. 
let act = Entity(type: "Record")
 act["tempo"] = "09:00" 
act["tentativi"] = "2" 
act["valore"] = "decimi"
I have read in an array all the data in the entity "Record" with "valore" = "decimi". 
is it correct let graph: Graph = Graph() 
let collection: Array<Entity> = graph.searchForEntity(properties: [(key: "valore", value: "decimi")])?

Comment: Looks correct. This will return all Entity types with that key / value pair. Graph really works in many different ways. It is designed to work the way you think.